# Locking Down ("Kiosk Mode") Android Devices

Tags: android, kiosk

How would you go about locking down an Android device while meeting the following requirements:

- Access to Wifi networks
- Access to a single company's App
- Ability to download/update to newer versions of the company's App
- Access to Bluetooth Printers

Obviously, this is a pretty general question, but I was hoping for some guidance.  Are there any existing solutions to this problem?  I am aware of apps like SecureLock and Device Lock, but do either of these allow application updating for JUST our application?

What about if we preconfigured the device to only have our application and nothing else, deleting all other applications?

Again, just looking for some direction/suggestions here.

Note: I am aware that essentially anything can be accomplished by releasing a custom version of Android, but implementation effort is a factor in which solution we will decide on.

Comment: There is one caveat, after which everything else is secondary.  A secure bootloader which cannot by bypassed.  If the device does not have one, then it can be rooted and after that, anything you do is circumventable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe most of this can be achieved by building a "launcher" app and making it full screen (cover the status bar). Check out the API Demo [Home](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html).

> Access to Wifi networks

You can use [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) to handle listing/connecting/etc.

> Access to a single company's App

Creating the main app as a launcher gives you the ability to control what other apps may be installed/uninstalled/launched/etc.

> Ability to download/update to newer versions of the company's App

This can easily be done by simply downloading the updated .apk (with a larger version code) and [opening the file via Intent to install](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969421/377260).

> Access to Bluetooth Printers

I don't know much about this, but if it can be done in a normal app, the launcher method covers it.