# Android - Create Launching Application

Tags: android, launching-application

I need some guide and help from you guys, What i want is as follows:

1. Replace the device home screen with a customizable screen that limits users to selected applications only. This should allow the administrator to select the applications from available list of applications.
2. Specify a URL for device redirection (in case of browsing)
3. Create a whitelist of acceptable URLs (no other URLs will be accepted)
4. Enable/Disable native Samsung Android device following features.

Android Market (App Store)
Camera
WiFi
Bluetooth
Microphone
Access Point

Now can anybody guide me what to do and where to start in android?
Your help will be really appreciable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by Evan, this is really the domain of Mobile Device Management (MDM) and involves a pretty heavy-handed control from the app.

There are a number of solutions already available such as [Air-Watch](http://www.air-watch.com/?cid=70150000000KJFG&gclid=CL-2n7ScpLgCFQghpQodqBEAAQ) or [Good](http://www1.good.com/) who specialize in exactly this sort of thing.

I think building your own from scratch would certainly not be trivial, though there is a lot of discussion which could help in getting you started (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165384/locking-down-kiosk-mode-android-devices/13168223#13168223) for instance).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

To archive that, I think you must build your own Android ROM. If you only want to install your HOME app to a device, user can easily get back old home screen.

Comment: hmmmm. I c. Thanks for nice addition in my views